# Using ASP.NET Identity with an Oracle database and thus Entity Framework 5

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

Is there any chance to use ASP.NET Identity with Entity Framework while connecting to an Oracle database?

The challenge seems to be some version conflicts:

- The [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) only targets Entity Framework 5 but not Entity Framework 6.
- The NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework targets EF6, not EF5.

It's not the code first feature that troubles me. It's getting the connection up and running and reading my user identity data from the Oracle database that bugs me.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone coming across this question now, ODAC 12c Release 3 supports Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is, of course, in implementing an UserStore class for the `IUserStore` (and `IUserPasswordStore` and `IUserClaimStore` and whatever one needs) interfaces.

Therein, it's just plain EF5 code that queries and updates the ASP.NET Identity tables.

Using this, the `UserManager` works just fine for accessing all identity data.